# Nested datasets in d3, updating the right element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having a problem with a nested dataset in d3. I have a number of rows, which should be rendered as text, and each row has a number of data points rendered as circles. My first attempt had the circles placed inside the  nodes, making them invisible. I then tried `labels.enter().append("g").append('text')`, which worked, now both the  and the  tags are places inside the same  tag. However, doing this, when I later do labels.transition().attr(...) to update the styling, the attr styling ends up on the  tag, not the  tag? (And since the text styling from the `enter` remains, it overrides, and nothing changes).

[Full listing here](https://gist.github.com/houshuang/e668a7e2f283a7b45241)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `labels` is defined here:

```
var labels = App.svg.selectAll("g").data(data, function(d) { return d.id });
```

Even though in your call to the enter selection you're adding both a `<g>` tag and `<text>` tag, your `labels` variable still refers to the `<g>` elements that you originally selected.

```
labels.enter().append("g").append('text')
```

If at a later point you want to access the `<text>` elements inside each label, you need to explicitly select them:

```
labels.select('text') // array of <text> elements for each <g> (label)
```